# define ajax callback overrides in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I have made an ajax prefilter to wait for a modal window to disappear before doing original callback, and it works great...

```
$.ajaxPrefilter ( options, originalOptions, jqXHR )->

    # perhaps these could be defined in a loop from an array
    jqXHROriginaldone = jqXHR.done
    jqXHROriginalfail = jqXHR.fail

    jqXHR.done = ->
        args = arguments
        myfunc = ->
            $(listener).off "ajax.progress.dismissed", myfunc
            jqXHROriginaldone args
        $(listener).on "ajax.progress.dismissed", myfunc

    jqXHR.fail = ->
        args = arguments
        myfunc = ->
            $(listener).off "ajax.progress.dismissed", myfunc
            jqXHROriginalfail args
        $(listener).on "ajax.progress.dismissed", myfunc
```

I don't like having to repeat my code for each status type... I want to change so that I can setup all statuses (done/fail/etc...) in a loop...

```
$.ajaxPrefilter ( options, originalOptions, jqXHR )->

    # object to store original callbacks for later use
    originals = {}

    for status in ['done','fail']

        originals[status] = jqXHR[status]
        jqXHR[status] = ->
            args = arguments
            myfunc = ->
                $(listener).off "ajax.progress.dismissed", myfunc
                originals[status] args
            $(listener).on "ajax.progress.dismissed", myfunc
```

It looks like eqivalent code to me, but it fails, and shows no errors in the console, just does not run the callback function.

Why does my looping method work?

Comment: I spent a few minutes trying to figure this out...couldn't find anything obvious. Did you throw a ton of `console.log`'s in there to see what/when stuff is happening?

Comment: @BradM thanks for spending the time. I did not put console logs in there, but I did step through the lines in the debugger, and everything I could inspect seemed fine. The functions seemed to be defined as expected, and it was calling them, except it never seemed to call the callback function. Clearly I am missing something - I doubt that javascript itself is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a function inside a loop raises a red flag. Your `status` variable won't be evaluated until it is actually used. If we look at your `myfunc`:

```
myfunc = ->
    $(listener).off "ajax.progress.dismissed", myfunc
    originals[status] args
```

we'll see a `status` reference that won't be evaluated until `myfunc` is called. When that happens, `status` will always be `'fail'` because that's what `status` was when the loop finished.

The usual solution in JavaScript is to use a SIF for the loop body:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    (function(i) {
        //...
    })(i);
```

but in CoffeeScript there is [`do`](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

So something like this should work better:

```
for status in ['done','fail']
    do (status) ->
        # What you have now...
```